# Apply function to corresponding elements in list of data frames

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames in R. All of the data frames in the list are of the same size. However, the elements may be of different types. For example,

[image]

I would like to apply a function to corresponding elements of data frame. For example, I want to use the paste function to produce a data frame such as

```
"1a" "2b" "3c"

"4d" "5e" "6f"
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in R. I know it is possible to use the Reduce function to apply a function on corresponding elements of dataframes within lists. But using the Reduce function in this case does not seem to have the desired effect.

```
Reduce(paste,l)
```

Produces:

```
"c(1, 4) c(\"a\", \"d\")" "c(2, 5) c(\"b\", \"e\")" "c(3, 6) c(\"c\", \"f\")"
```

Wondering if I can do this without writing messy for loops. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Screenshots are not reproducible as example data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `Reduce`, use `Map`.

```
 # not quite the same as your data
 l <- list(data.frame(matrix(1:6,ncol=3)),
           data.frame(matrix(letters[1:6],ncol=3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
 # this returns a list
 LL <- do.call(Map, c(list(f=paste0),l))
 #
 as.data.frame(LL)
 #  X1 X2 X3
 # 1 1a 3c 5e
 # 2 2b 4d 6f
```

Comment: Wow, that worked like magic! So do.call feeds the function paste0 and each item in l to Map, however, Map at any given time has access to only 1 item in l, so how is it able to paste together things from different items across the list? If that's not the case then why doesn't Map(paste,l) simply work?

Comment: You could simplify a little with `do.call(Map,c(paste0,l))`

Answer (score 4):

To explain @mnel's excellent answer a bit more, consider the simple example of summing the corresponding elements of two vectors:

```
Map(sum,1:3,4:6)

[[1]]
[1] 5  # sum(1,4)

[[2]]
[1] 7  # sum(2,5)

[[3]]
[1] 9  # sum(3,6)

Map(sum,list(1:3,4:6))

[[1]]
[1] 6  # sum(1:3)

[[2]]
[1] 15 # sum(4:6)
```

Why the second one is the case might be made more obvious by adding a second list, like:

```
Map(sum,list(1:3,4:6),list(0,0))

[[1]]
[1] 6  # sum(1:3,0)

[[2]]
[1] 15 # sum(4:6,0)
```

Now, the next is more tricky. As the help page `?do.call` states:

```
 ‘do.call’ constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
 function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.
```

So, doing:

```
do.call(Map,c(sum,list(1:3,4:6)))
```

calls `Map` with the inputs of the list `c(sum,list(1:3,4:6))`, which looks like:

```
[[1]] # first argument to Map
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum") # the 'sum' function

[[2]] # second argument to Map
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]] # third argument to Map
[1] 4 5 6
```

...and which is therefore equivalent to:

```
Map(sum, 1:3, 4:6)
```

Looks familiar! It is equivalent to the first example at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! Pretty elegant!