# Apply a function (e.g. mean) using corresponding elements of dataframes in list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a list of 10 data frames where every element represents a different variable.

```
l1 <- list(d1=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6)),
           d2=data.frame(a=c(3,2,1), b=c(6,5,4)),
       d3=data.frame(a=c(2,2,2), b=c(5,5,5)))
```

I would like to get a mean on every corresponding element of all data frames.
So for element [1,1], I would have a mean of (1,3,2).
I can do it for a single position with:

```
m1_1<-mean(unlist(lapply(l1, function(x) (x[[1,1]]))))
```

Is there a way to extend the indexing on the whole data frame?
thanks,
M.

Comment: Related: e.g. joran's answer: [apply function to elements over a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085110/apply-function-to-elements-over-a-list). [Apply function to corresponding elements in list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298482/apply-function-to-corresponding-elements-in-list-of-data-frames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` to get the sum (`+`) of corresponding elements, and then divide by the `length` of the `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, l1)/length(l1)
```

---

Or for more general case convert to `array`, and then use `apply`

```
ar1 <- array(unlist(l1), dim = c(dim(l1[[1]]), length(l1)))
apply(ar1, 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
apply(ar1, 1:2, median, na.rm = TRUE)
apply(ar1, 1:2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have written more generally a function, not only a mean. I also want to get the standard deviation and a few other values.